# stripe testing working fine on localhost but not working on server , its not dedecting testing amount from card

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, stripe-payments, silverstripe

I have been trying to integrate strip payment gateway system. Everything working perfectly fine on localhost. But when i uploaded to the server it does not work.

Comment: What isn't working though? And you need https / ssl for stripe to work.  Without SSL/https, for example, the stripe elemenst input will be blank

Answer (score 0):

Are you running it in HTTPS?

Is the rest of your frontend/backend working properly communicating with eachother?

Are you getting any errors?

Comment: I am testing it on http://gpantry-001-site1.gtempurl.com, there is no domain added yet. there is no error, it returns me to order page

Comment: do need to add a domain and use SSL. please reply

Answer (score 0):

Stripe ***Forces*** HTTPS for all services using TLS (SSL).It is like their requirement that must be fulfilled. Please Have a look [Here](https://stripe.com/docs/security#tls).

So in order to make it work on a server, SSL should be installed on that server to work with Stripe.js libraries. In addition, all pages should be served over HTTPS. Further readings.. [Here](https://stripe.com/docs/security/stripe#ssl)